# Ubuntu 19.10 won't auto-select my headeset's mic as input

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 19.10, headphones, microphone

I have Sony 1000M3 headphones. They have a microphone. I am able to connect them to my computer running ubuntu 19.10 and hear sound automatically. They connect as A2DP, and are recognized as headsets.

However I always have to go in settings and choose the mic as input even though my computer has no other sound input option.

How can this be done automatically upon connection?

In addition, for some reason my headset goes into "call" mode when I select the mic input, it doesn't do this on my mac or windows, is there a way to avoid this on ubuntu as well?

Thanks